# expected type-specifier error, any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to implement a DEQUE using double linked list.

DEQUE.h

```
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Node{
    Node(const T& data):data(data), next(0), prev(0) {}
    public:
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
        T data;
};

template <typename T>
class DEQUE
{

//interface
};
```

DEQUE.cpp

```
template <class T>
void DEQUE< T > ::AddFirst(T t){
    Node<T>* temp = new Node(t);
    if ( counter != 0 ) {
        temp->next = head;
        temp->prev = 0 ;
        head->prev = temp;
        head =temp;
        counter++;
    }

    else{
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
        temp->next = 0;
        temp->prev = 0;
        counter++;
    }
};
```

I am getting expected type-specifier before 'Node' error on the line

```
Node<T>* temp = new Node(t);
```

what am I doing wrong here? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You are missing `#include "DEQUE.h"`

Comment: Somewhat related:  It is *highly* likely that template implementation should be moved to your deque.h header file. [Read this for why.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file?s=2|2.6716).

Comment: @DrewDormann- DEQUE.h is there, I just showed the problematic part of the code.

Comment: @WhozCraig - I know its not the portable way, but i am including the cpp file path in the main file and its working fine except for the error above, another way is to include DEQUE.cpp in the DEQUE.h so that when DEQUE.h is included, so is DEQUE.cpp.

Comment: @user3259345 Portability has nothing to do with it.You could split it up countless ways, but *why*? People see a .cpp file, they expect a *translation unit*. If you want to go from Trenton to New York, you can certainly go by way of LA, Moscow, and Heathrow I suppose, but *why*. Anyway, best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig - What you are saying makes complete sense. Since I am knew at this, I am into learning what all can work besides what works best. Thanks for the input, best of luck to you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the type when creating an instance of `Node`:

```
Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>(t);
                        ^^^  missing.
```

The type used to create an instance of `Node` is not automatically assumed to be same as the type used for `DEQUE`. You have to explicitly specify it.